# What is the difference between Cordova Build and Cordova Prepare

Tags: cordova

Is there any difference between **Cordova Build Android** and **Cordova Prepare Android** Commands ? 
[Reference is added here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Answer (score 14):

Prepare copies your www assets and any plugins into the appropriate platform folder. Build actually then compiles this into the binary for that platform.

You would use prepare if you planned on doing a build with the platform's tools (Eclipse, XCode, etc) and maybe want to modify something first.

Comment: Does this mean prepare command only is used to import the phonegap project to eclipse/xcode  and make further changes in IDE but not in WWW as html files ?